# simple barchart and axis are side by side. SVG graph

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I have a stacked bar chart in the below codepen https://codepen.io/a166617/pen/qBXvzQd

As you can see the codepen, it doesn't show graph on x-axis and y-axis line. barchart slides away to the right. Can someone please let me know how to put barchart on the x-axis and y-axis of graph?

```
<g class="grid x-grid" id="xGrid">
  <line x1="90" x2="90" y1="5" y2="371"></line>
</g>
<g class="grid y-grid" id="yGrid">
  <line x1="90" x2="705" y1="370" y2="370"></line>
</g>
```

The code to achieve the line for the x-axis and y-axis is as follows. But somehow the graph does not show up on the line axis. Can someone please guide me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would solve this is by using [css positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). I've added some additional code on your codepen. It's viable if your graph has static values. Check it out [here](https://codepen.io/ghostpants/pen/dyzLmBG). I've added this custom class on the `div` that contains the bars and title.

```
.mGraph > svg {
  position: relative;
  left: -40rem;
  top: -.65rem;
}

.mGraph > div {
  position: relative;
  left: -40rem;
  top: -.65rem;
}

.mGraph > text {
  position: relative;
  left: -50rem;
}
```